# The tests in selenium are not runing at the desired order

Tags: selenium, junit4

Although that i'm using `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`
My tests are not runing at the desired order

I have 2 tests,
The first tets name is: aTest_Login()
The second test name is: bTest_CreateContact()

Sometimes the second test is runing before the first test.

Comment: Could you please paste the entire source code you have written so we can do a deeper analysis? Just by face value of what you have written it should work.

Comment: The entire code is long and i don't think that in this case it will help,  As i know the `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`  should order the tests by they name, If you think otherwise tell me  and i'll copy my code to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowning details about `@FixMethodOrder`, it seems to be a JUnit thing. JUnit is, as the name states, a framework to execute unit tests. Unit tests must not have any depenencies or links between them (that's the idea of unit tests), so the order in which they are executed must not influence the result, they are commutative. If you want to execute tests in a specific order for integration and gui tests I would strongly recommend to use something supporting test dependencies like [Test NG](https://testng.org)

In TestNG you can define test groups and specify test dependencies. If you want to run gui tests the first "root" test could be whether or not your test system is online (because all you gui tests will fail if the system is offline it makes sense to only have one failed test, saying the system was offline).

```
@Test(groups = "login") 
public void aTest_Login() {
   ...
}

@Test(groups = {"contacts", "creation"}, dependsOnGroups = "login") 
public void bTest_CreateContact(){
  // this test will only be executed if all tests of the group "login" passed
}
```

TestNG has a migration guide from JUnit and offers other stuff regarding integration- and gui tests. You should check it out